# How do I get syntax highlighting of source code files within Quick Look back in Lion?

Tags: macos, quicklook

Source code files viewed using Quick Look on Snow Leopard had syntax highlighting. Unfortunately the syntax highlighting has disappeared on OS X Lion. Is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think Snow Leopard did that by default, you most likely had a QuickLook plugin installed, such as [qlcolorcode](http://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/) or [colorqc2](http://www.samlepirate.net/colorqc2). You can simply install this again in Lion.

Comment: Can anybody with Snow Leopard confirm this? I honestly don't remember installing a Quick Look plugin to get syntax highlighting.

Comment: I can confirm that there is no syntax highlighting done on Obj-C or python code viewed via Quick Look on Snow Leopard. You must have had a plugin installed.

Comment: tx, qlcolorcode is still working for me in 10.9

Answer (score 7):

Actually, Xcode 3.x included a Quicklook plugin for source codes. With the intruduction of Xcode 4.x, such plugin has disappeared.

I have personallly tried to use qlcolorcode and colorqc2 on Lion, but both are not stable/reliable enough (slow response, sometimes missing quicklook). An updated version of the plugins would be welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The Xcode 3 plugin was found at /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/SourceCode.qlgenerator
Unfortunately I don't think this can be made to work now. :(

Answer (score -2):

Guys you can do this procedure bellow:

To fix this, open a new Terminal window and enter these commands to open vim’s configuration file:

```
$ cd /usr/share/vim
$ sudo vim vimrc
```

Press the <kbd>i</kbd> key to switch vim to Insertion Mode, then enter these lines below the `set backspace=2` line:

```
set ai                  " auto indenting
set history=100         " keep 100 lines of history
set ruler               " show the cursor position
syntax on               " syntax highlighting
set hlsearch            " highlight the last searched term
filetype plugin on      " use the file type plugins

" When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
autocmd BufReadPost *
\ if ! exists("g:leave_my_cursor_position_alone") |
\ if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
\ exe "normal g'\"" |
\ endif |
\ endif
```

Press the <kbd>⎋ esc</kbd> key to take vim out of Insertion Mode, then press <kbd>:</kbd> (colon) followed by <kbd>x</kbd> to save the file and exit.

It worked for me thanks.

Comment: Sadly this has nothing to do with QuickLook, just Vim.

Comment: I'll second that!