# Syntax highlighting in QuickLook

Tags: macos, quicklook

I'm looking for a way to have syntax highlighting for my source codes in El-Capitan's QuickLook without installing TextMate. Previously I had TextMate and I got hooked to this feature.

Googling this bring some really old posts on web such as:

[How do I get syntax highlighting of source code files within Quick Look back in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23042/how-do-i-get-syntax-highlighting-of-source-code-files-within-quick-look-back-in)

These are not maintained anymore based on their SVN/Git repo:[QLColorCode](https://github.com/n8gray/QLColorCode/graphs/contributors) and [colorqc2](http://www.samlepirate.net/colorqc2)

Surprisingly there are also some people who wants to get rid of syntax highlighting after installing TextMate:

[Remove Quicklook Syntax Highlighting with TextMate2?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128516/remove-quicklook-syntax-highlighting-with-textmate2)

Having syntax highlighting is essential for me but I don't want to install a full featured text editor just to use on library of it!

My rationale in not installing TextMate on my El-Capitan is that I have RStudio and Atom which are way more customized/customizable than TextMate.

I would appreciate any suggestion/solution that is maintained properly, work with el-capitan.

Cheers,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally ... I found [page](https://github.com/sindresorhus/quick-look-plugins) providing some QuickLook solutions based on Homebrew's caskroom:

```
brew cask install qlcolorcode
```

This is based on a fork from and [old](https://github.com/n8gray/QLColorCode/graphs/contributors) repository but is maintained and developed [quite well](https://github.com/anthonygelibert/QLColorCode/graphs/contributors) at least until today.

I gave it a shot and it works just fine, though I still prefer the dark theme of TextMate :)